# How to use RESTful controller within Laravel 5

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel

I'm working on a form with Laravel 5, following up a tutorial from [Openclassropms](http://openclassrooms.com) which is about Laravel 4, and that really gave me a hard time.

Anyway, I'm trying to change these lines in my routes.php file:

```
Route::get('users' , 'UsersController@getInfos');
Route::post('users', 'UsersController@postInfos');
```

with this line :

```
Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
```

but doing so breaks my form, I can still see the input text area but submitting it gives me the following error :

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145

Here are my controllers and templates:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
class UsersController extends Controller {

    public function getInfos()
    {
        return \View::make('infos');
    }

    public function postInfos()
    {
        echo 'The name is ' . Input::get('nom');
    }

}

@extends('tempform')
```

and

```
@section('content')
    {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'users')) !!}
        {!! Form::label('nom', 'Enter your name:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('nom') !!}
        {!! Form::submit('Submit') !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
```

Also, I use a different url once I make the change as stated initially in the tutorial: gappsl/users >> gappsl/users/info

Comment: Laravel 5 is really quite different to Laravel 4.*, I would recommend not following a Laravel 4 tutorial unless you're going to use version 4 of the framework.

Comment: Do you know of any good beginner-friendly tutorials for Laravel 5? and moreover, should I keep working on Laravel 5 or make the switch to version 4.2 in your opinion?

Comment: There are a few Laravel 5 from scratch tutorials around but it was only officially released Feb 2015. A google should find them. I would learn 5, there seems little point putting time into 4 at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a new method in your controller called `getIndex()` or `postIndex()` depending on which HTTP verb you will be using. This way the `/users` route will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Route::controller()` method then it is always looking for the functions starting with the HTTP Verb.

In your case, If you want to point the `postInfos()` through your form. Then you need to change your form definition to this:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'users/infos', 'method'=>'POST')) !!}
```

**Or**

If you have any confusions regarding which routes to use, then simply go to command line within your application root directory and type `php artisan route:list`.

There you can find which URI points to which method with full controller path.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the line form open to :

```
  {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'users/post-infos')) !!}
```

to address your `postInfos()` function

Comment: Here is the corresponding documentation
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Comment: Gonna try this one as well, it will probably come in handy too, thanks Edwin.

Comment: Actually it does not work like @EdwinKrause said. If you want to call for example postInfos route you have to use ```/users/infos``` path with POST method. Analogically if you want to call patchHelloWorld you should use ```/users/hello-world``` with PATCH method. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: I was thinking this myself and you're right Maksym it actually worked with /users/infos, not with users/post-infos like Edwin pointed out, but he pointed me to the right direction and now I'm kinda getting the grasp of it. Thank you for your help!!